# When did Koko's mirror end up in Banri's stuff?

Tags: golden-time

Spoilers for the ending of Golden Time:

> The twin mirrors are switched in the final episode. Yama is seen giving Koko the broken one in the previous one, but I missed the scene when the one belonging to Koko ends up in Banri's place.

Is that shown? If it is, in what episode?

Comment: It is shown IIRC, tried to skim over the episodes but didn't find it.

Comment: @Mindwin I am not sure but in episode 12 at end when ko koko and banri leave room to take pic outside,camera focuses mirror,it can be mirror of koko.